# How to set kern Persian Numbers in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to kern Persian numbers but `.kerning()` doesn't work.

Do you know any another way to set kern in persian numbers?

```
Text(250000, format: .number)
    .kerning(5)
            
Text("250000")
    .kerning(5)
            
Text(25000.asCurrencyFa)
    .kerning(5)
```

[image]

This is my extension how I format the numbers:

```
extension Int {
    var asCurrencyFa: String {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .currency
        formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "fa_IR")
        formatter.currencySymbol = ""
        
        return  formatter.string(from: self as NSNumber)!
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kerning (really "expansion" here since this isn't really kerning IMO) is a function of the font, and the default system font (`.SFUI-Regular`, but I'm pretty sure it's actually SF Arabic) does not appear to support expanding Persian digits. It will expand Persian letters somewhat. For example, فارسی, with `.kern(10)` displays this way vs "normal."

[image: فارسی without and then with "kern"]

That said, there are fonts that support expanding Persian digits. For example, Geeza Pro:

```
let ctFont = CTFontCreateWithName("GeezaPro" as CFString, 16, nil)
...
        Text(25000.asCurrencyFa)
            .font(Font(ctFont))

        Text(25000.asCurrencyFa)
            .font(Font(ctFont))
            .kerning(10)
```

[image: 25,000 normal and then expanded in Geeza Pro]

---

One approach to get the "look" is to add HAIR SPACE U+200A between all the characters:

```
    return formatter.string(from: self as NSNumber)!
        .map(String.init).joined(separator: "\u{200A}")
```

This will be a little wider than expected because the HAIR SPACE has width of its own, plus there are two "kernings" per digit pair rather than one. But I do believe it will work with every font. I tried using various zero-width spaces, but they're mostly ignored, except around the comma.

Comment: Thanks, this worked but I'm using another font.